# SlickGrid onSelectedRowsChanged not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slickgrid

I have the following issue with slickgrid:

1. Left click row 1 (onSelectedRowsChanged fires as expected)
2. Hold down the control button
3. Left click row 2 (onSelectedRowsChanged fires as expected)
4. Left click row 1 (onSelectedRowsChanged fires as expected)
5. Let go of the control button
6. *Click row 1* **(onSelectedRowsChanged does not fire! If you click on the same row 1 cell as before)**

Issues as described on step 6 above. Here is a link to a jsfiddler showing the issues: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fortesl/oLj8otsj/1/

Code also attached:

```
         var grid;
     var data = [];
     var columns = [{
         id: "title",
         name: "Title",
         field: "title",
         width: 300,
         selectable: false,
         resizable: false
     }, {
         id: "priority",
         name: "Priority",
         field: "priority",
         width: 200,
         selectable: false,
         resizable: false
     }];

     var options = {
         editable: true,
         enableAddRow: true,
         enableCellNavigation: true,
         forceFitColumns: true,
         autoEdit: false
     };

     for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         var d = (data[i] = {});
         d["title"] = "Task " + (i + 1);
         d["priority"] = "Medium";
     }

     grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

     grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());

     grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function () {
         var selectedRows = grid.getSelectedRows();
         for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
             selectedRows[i] = selectedRows[i] + 1;
         }
         $('.selected-rows')[0].innerHTML = selectedRows;
     });
     grid.onClick.subscribe(function () {
         $('.selected-rows')[0].innerHTML = '';
     });
```

Please help

Comment: Cool, what you got so far? Show some code

Comment: example?  Use JSFIDDLE if you want us to debug your code.

Comment: http://casivaagustin.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/show-me-the-source-yoda.jpg

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle. Thank you

Comment: Updated jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/fortesl/oLj8otsj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by handling the OnClick event and calling setSelectedRows from the handler. Shown below:

```
                grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e) {
                var cell = $scope.grid.getCellFromEvent(e);
                var row = (cell) ? cell.row : 0;
                var rows = [row];
                grid.setSelectedRows(rows);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the cell (not the row) is active and in the slick.grid.js there is a check making sure the trigger is not activated if clicking on a cell already active.

Take a look at the

```
 function handleClick(e)...
```

inside the source code file and you'll see the check in question.

Answer (score 0):

OnClick event and calling setSelectedRows gives another highlightcolor (more like yellow-pink) of the selected row than onSelectedRowsChanged (blue in my application)

Comment: Add some more details to it.